# Devise - undefined method `stringify_keys' for [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 4 and devise (3.2.2). But when I am trying to sign up, I am getting exception

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for [:email, :password,
>   :password_confirmation]:Array

Below is the method where I am getting the exception.

```
def build_resource(hash=nil)
  self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
end
```

I have checked that value of `hash` is `[:email, :password, :password_confirmation]`, shouldn't it be a hash instead of array?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be. In the default `Devise::RegistrationsController`, in the `create` action the first line is

`build_resource(sign_up_params)`

The `sign_up_params` method should return the permitted request parameters for sign up; by default these will be `email`, `password`, and `password_confirmation`.

You must've changed something from the defaults. Have you changed the permitted params at all (via `configure_permitted_parameters` in `ApplicationController`, for example?)? Have you overridden the `create` action on the registrations controller? Have you overridden the `sign_up_params` method?

More information is needed to give a definitive answer, but those are the places to look.

Comment: My Bad, I have overridden registration controller when my gem version was 3.0 and now its 3.2.2